# How to change nature of graph from shaded to distinct lines?

Tags: matlab

The following MATLAB code generates a shaded region on the graph. I am more interested in getting distinct lines. The easiest way to do so is by increasing 'dt' and reducing ii. But that is not working.

```
global k1 k2 k3 k4 k5
k1=55;
k2=2.0e+03;
k3=4e+01;
k4=0.001;
k5=200;
n=10000001;
dt=0.0001;
x=zeros(n,1);
y=zeros(n,1);
z=zeros(n,1);
t=zeros(n,1);
x(1)=0.9999; 
y(1)=0.38462;
z(1)=0.1995;
t(1)=0.0;
for ii=1:10000000
    t(ii+1)=t(ii)+dt;
    x(ii+1)=x(ii)+dt*(-k5*(k1+k3)*x(ii)+ k3*x(ii)*z(ii) + k4*z(ii) + k2*y(ii) );
    y(ii+1)=y(ii)+dt*(k1*x(ii) - k2*y(ii));
    z(ii+1)=z(ii)+dt*(-k3*x(ii)*z(ii) - k4*z(ii) + k3*k5);
end
%plot(t,x,'b');
%plot(t,y,'g');
plot(t,z,'r');
%plot3(x,y,z);
%legend('x','y','z');
%hold on;
grid on;
%axis([0 10 0 10 0 10]);
%end
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: reducing ii seems to work for me. What do you mean by that is not working?

Comment: By not working I mean that I am not getting the same nature or rather distinct lines which I expect to be sinusoidal in nature.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want? Try: `n=20001;
dt=0.00001;` and use `for ii = 1:n`. Is that close to what you want?